# Is it possible to have a member pointer to an array in a struct?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to have a member pointer to an array in a struct? I would like to do something like below:

```
struct A  
{  
   int array[10];  
   int sizeOfArray;  
};  

template<int size>
class B  
{  

public:  

   B(int (A::*arrayLocation)[size],  
     int A::*arraySize):  
     memberArray(arrayLocation),  
     memberArraySize(arraySize))  
  {  
  }  

   void setValue(A* pobj1)  
   {  
      for(int i = 0; i < pobj1->*memberArraySize; i++)  
      {  
         (pobj1->*memberArray)[i] = 1;  
      }  
   }  


private:  
  int (A::*memberArray)[size];  
  int A::*arraySize;  
};  

int main()  
{  
    A obj2;
    B<10> obj1(&A::array, &A::sizeOfArray);  
    obj1.setValue(&obj2);
}
```

Comment: Format code by indenting it four spaces. Do not use `<code>` or any such tags.

Comment: Why would you want to do this in the first place? const member pointers pointing outside of the class is flawed OO design, and non-const member pointers doing the same is terrible, obfuscated design.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer to an array in a struct is no different than a pointer to an array.

If what you want is a "pointer" that, given an object and an offset, returns the value of the corresponding element in some member array of that object, then you can write it as a "getter" function.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you want to and if compiler supports it. But as @Lundin already said it is almost always a bad idea. Pointer to member is a feature that may be useful in a very rare cases. IMHO pointer to array member as well as pointer to array is never useful (as pointer to the first member is always used).